# How to disable lazy loading in Safari iframe to improve performance?

Tags: performance, iframe, safari, lazy-loading

After upgrading iOS to 16.4, I encountered an abnormal  performance in the Safari browser.
After the outer container page index.html embeds a page pc.htm with poor performance (LCP < 10s) through , the performance of pc.htm becomes worse, LCP >= 20s, compared with pc.htm directly in Safari The difference between opening and closing is 15s.

Code for reference:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        html,body {
            height: 100vh;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

<h1>test</h1>
<iframe title="lebi.oa" style="width: 100%; height: 95%;" src="./quickbi.htm"></iframe>


</body>

</html>
```

when i check [Safari 16.4 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari-release-notes/safari-16_4-release-notes#HTML)

it shows :

> HTML
> New Features
> Added support for lazy loading iframes.

but there is no information on how to disable lazy loading

is there any attribute of  to disable the lazy loading?

Comment: Try to add `loading=eager` attribute to your `iframe` tag. If it doesn't work (though it should), try to preload target page with `<link rel="preload" href="./quickbi.htm" as="document" />` tag in the `head` section.